# UE4: How to cast actor to blueprint interface type

Tags: interface, casting, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

**I'd like to store a variable of type `Actor` in a variable which is of a BP interface type.**

Is there something like a `Cast To BP Interface` BP node? I know about the [Does Implement Interface](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/DoesImplementInterface/index.html) (which does not return a reference to the interface instance) and the [Cast To](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Blueprints/UserGuide/CastNodes/index.html) (which doesn't work for interfaces) nodes. But these do not allow me to get an instance of my BP interface type.

I know that I could store the actor in a variable of type `Actor` and then invoke the interface functions on that actor. But that seems like a type system workaround to me. That's why I'd like to enfore the interface type on the variable.

[image: Bluprint node setup]

Comment: `Cast To` does work, it just doesn't show up in the context. Disable 'Context Sensitive' or click in an empty place in the graph to create a `Cast To` node, and then hook it up to your actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cast To` does work, it just doesn't show up in the context. Disable 'Context Sensitive' or click in an empty place in the graph to create a `Cast To` node, and then hook it up to your actor.

(Answered on behalf of @Rotem)